# Accessing a component state from a sibling button

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a page that will render a dynamic number of expandable rows based on data from a query.

Each expandable row contains a grid as well as a button which should add a new row to said grid.

The button needs to access and update the state of the grid.

My problem is that I don't see any way to do this from the onClick handler of a button.

Additionally, you'll see the ExpandableRow component is cloning the children (button and grid) defined in SomePage, which further complicates my issue.

Can anyone suggest a workaround that might help me accomplish my goal?

```js
const SomePage = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <MyPageComponent>
        <ExpandableRowsComponent>
          <button onClick={(e) => { /* Need to access MyGrid state */ }} />
            Add Row
          </button>
          <MyGrid>
            <GridColumn field="somefield" />
          </MyGrid>
        </ExpandableRowsComponent>
      </MyPageComponent>
    </>
  );
};

const ExpandableRowsComponent = (props) => {
  const data = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((dataItem) => (
        <ExpandableRow id={dataItem.id} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const ExpandableRow = (props) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="row-item">
      <div className="row-item-header">
        <img
          className="collapse-icon"
          onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}
        />
      </div>

      {expanded && (
        <div className="row-item-content">
          {React.Children.map(props.children, (child => cloneElement(child, { id: props.id })))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: if you need a button in each` expandableRow`, why don't you have the button on the component, rather than on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main ways to achieve this

1. Hoist the state to common ancestors
2. Using ref (sibling communication based on this [tweet](https://twitter.com/realamirhe/status/1362457891609919489))

```
const SomePage = (props) => {
  const ref = useRef({})
  return (
    <>
      <MyPageComponent>
        <ExpandableRowsComponent>
          <button onClick={(e) => { console.log(ref.current.state) }} />
            Add Row
          </button>
          <MyGrid ref={ref}>
            <GridColumn field="somefield"  />
          </MyGrid>
        </ExpandableRowsComponent>
      </MyPageComponent>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Steps** required for seconds step if you want to not only access state but also update state

1. You must define a `forwardRef` component
2. Update ref in `useEffect` or pass your API object via `useImerativeHandle`
   You can also use or get inspired by [react-aptor](https://github.com/amirHossein-Ebrahimi/react-aptor).

⭐ If you are only concerned about the UI part (the placement of button element)

> [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.
> (Mentioned point by @Sanira Nimantha)